# Calculate Rotational Intertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, inertia

If a can of soup, and a can of beans (tightly packed), are set in a race down a rough hill (has friction), the soup wins, because the inside of the can (soup) is not drawing energy from the system.

If the can of beans is of mass 16oz (0.454kg) evenly spread, and the radius is say .05m, how can I calculate the difference in acceleration between the two. I assume I would have to calculate normal force on the inline, and then factor in the force used to accelerate the beans. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As homework questions go this one is nicely conceptual. Just the kind of basic question that we do answer.

Comment: Thank you. I enjoy physics, but workload from other classes has caused me to have a trying grasp on rotation. Thanks for helping